# Binding WPF Combobox to DataTable via XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a DataGrid that I am attempting to populate using a dynamic DataTemplate (depending on context, it will show a TextBlock, CheckBox, ComboBox, etc); I have the DataGrid bound to an object containing the data I need, but I'm running into trouble when it comes time to set the ItemsSource of the ComboBox cells to a DataTable contained in my object:

```
 public class Attribute
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public SqlDataSet.OptionDataTable Options { get; set; }
}
...
List<Attribute> attributes = new List<Attribute>();
...
datagrid.ItemsSource = attributes;
```

Unless I misunderstand the method I'm using for the dynamic cell types (which is quite likely, as this is my first WPF project), I don't believe I have the option of binding my ComboBoxes directly to my Attribute.Options via back-end code, which seems to be the common answer to this situation.

My XAML:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="StringTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OptionTemplate">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Options}}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                  SelectedValuePath="OptionID"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:DataGridCellTemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector" 
                                        StringTemplate="{StaticResource StringTemplate}" 
                                        OptionTemplate="{StaticResource OptionTemplate}"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value"
        CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

The ComboBoxes appear correctly when run in this fashion, but the contents are blank.

And my DataGridCellTemplateSelector ([based heavily on this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5ffa3a6a-cea4-411e-aba5-0d7807b3949b/change-cell-datatype-in-a-grid-control-wpf-mvvm?forum=wpf)):

```
public class DataGridCellTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate StringTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate OptionTemplate { get; set; }

    public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is Attribute)
        {
            switch ((item as Attribute).Type)
            {
                case "Text":
                    return StringTemplate;
                case "Option":
                    return OptionTemplate;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

If there's a way to access the ComboBox to set the ItemsSource via code, that would be awesome as well. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Where you define DataTable

Comment: Debug method **Options** to find out what happened, check **vs output window** make sure there was no binding error.